# Does Agile Opportunist work with reach weapons?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-actions

I'm playing a level 16 Cunning Bard in DnD4e.  The "melee" striker in our party is a Barbarian with a reach weapon (he also has a focus on charge attacks).  Since I have access to all sorts of sliding shenanigans, I figured Agile Opportunist would be a great feat for him to take. 
the feat states:

> When you are pulled, pushed, or slid into a square adjacent to an enemy, 
>   you can use an opportunity action to make a melee basic attack against that enemy.

Can we interpret the word "adjacent" in this feat to mean any square in which he has threatening reach?  This interpretation is based on the text from PHB1 about opportunity attacks, which says:

> Some creatures have an ability
>   called threatening reach. This lets them make opportunity
>   attacks against nonadjacent enemies. If an enemy
>   leaves a square that’s within the creature’s reach, or if
>   an enemy anywhere within the creature’s reach makes
>   a ranged attack or an area attack, the creature can
>   make an opportunity attack against that enemy.

Are we stretching the intent of AO too much to say that the Barbarian could attack a creature within his REACH when I push/pull/slide him.
As an interesting side-note, the barbarian also has a feature that allows him to substitute one of his At-will powers for times when he is granted a melee basic attack.
The up-shot would be that he could get an off-turn at-will if I can slide him within reach of a baddie.
Thoughts?  Am I trying to exploit this too much? does it threaten to foul up balance?  Or is this just clever synergy and strategy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Adjacent means adjacent.

Even if you have threatening reach, you are not making an opportunity attack, you are taking an opportunity action to make a basic attack. While the *result* is the same, they are not the same thing.

When a power intends for you to be able to use your reach it will say "within reach" or "within range"

Also note that achieving threatening reach for a PC is very hard and never permanent.